# May I change the held type in a std::variant from within a call to std::visit

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

Does the following code invoke undefined behaviour?

```
std::variant<A,B> v = ...;

std::visit([&v](auto& e){
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(e)>,A>)
    e.some_modifying_operation_on_A();
  else {
    int i = e.some_accessor_of_B();
    v = some_function_returning_A(i); 
  }
}, v);
```

In particular, when the variant does not contain an `A`,
this code re-assigns an `A` while still holding a reference to the previously held object of type `B`.
However, because the reference is not used anymore after the assignment,
I feel the code is fine.
However, would a standard-library be free to implement `std::visit`
in a way such that the above is undefined behaviour?

Comment: Do you want quotes from the standard to back up the answer(s) you get?

Comment: From looking at [\[variant.visit\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.visit), I'm 99% sure this code is compliant and guaranteed not to have UB, since `std::visit(vis, variant)` should be equivalent to `vis(get</* active member */>(variant))`, but I'm not confident enough in reading the standard to be certain

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't need actual quotes from the standard, as long as the experts here can agree on the answer:-).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code is fine.

There is no requirement in the specification of [`std::visit`](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.visit) that the visitor not change the alternative of any of the variants it is invoked on. The only requirement is:

> *Requires*: For each valid pack `m`, `e(m)` shall be a valid expression. All such expressions shall be of the same type and value category; otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

Your visitor is a valid expression for each `m` and always returns `void`, so it satisfies the requirements and has well-defined behavior.